# Identify Potential Duplicates in Two Dataframes Even if Dates are Not the Same (7d range)

Tags: python, loops, python-datetime

I have two datasframes with repeated transactions but the same transaction may have two different dates in each (appears within a 7d time window).

I am trying to isolate repeated transactions based on a date range of +/- 7d but am not able to do it.

The code below simply looks at 'Date', 'Amount' and (if date and amount match) it compares 'Category' and highlights if the same transaction has been categorised differently.

Could you please help me to modify this code so that it compares Date Ranges, not a spot Date and still identifies duplicates that appear within a 7d window?

```
import pandas as pd

# convert the 'Date' column of both dataframes to datetime objects
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

# merge the two dataframes based on 'Amount' and 'Date'
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Amount', 'Date'], how='outer', suffixes=['_df1', '_df2'])

# create a new column 'Differences' to store the differences in category
merged_df['Differences'] = ''

# iterate over the rows of the merged dataframe
for index, row in merged_df.iterrows():
    # if the row is unique to df1
    if pd.isnull(row['Category_df2']):
        merged_df.at[index, 'Differences'] = 'Unique to first dataframe'
    # if the row is unique to df2
    elif pd.isnull(row['Category_df1']):
        merged_df.at[index, 'Differences'] = 'Unique to second dataframe'
    # if the row is present in both dataframes
    else:
        # if the categories are different
        if row['Category_df1'] != row['Category_df2']:
            merged_df.at[index, 'Differences'] = 'Category is different'
        # if the categories are the same
        else:
            merged_df.at[index, 'Differences'] = 'Category is the same'

# print the merged dataframe with the differences highlighted in the 'Differences' column
print(merged_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Category', 'Amount'], how='outer', suffixes=['_df1', '_df2'])

merged_df = merged_df.dropna()

merged_df['date_diff'] = abs((merged_df.date__df1 - merged_df.date_df2).dt.days)

duplicatedf = merged_df[merged_df.date_diff <=7]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?